# How to bind to OpenCV for GNAT?

Tags: opencv, binding, ada, gnat

Can anybody tell me how to find or create a binding to [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) for GNAT?
I want to use Ada2005 to implement some program with OpenCV (1.0 or 2.X),
but I don't know how. Can anybody teach me how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Teaching you how to create a binding to a complex library is beyond the scope of [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but you might start with this [tutorial](http://www.dwheeler.com/lovelace/s16s3.htm). Then study the relevant GNAT library sources, e.g. `Ada.Numerics`, and other [existing Ada bindings](http://www.adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Bindings&Title=Ada%20Bindings). Among others, [*Ada 2005 Math Extensions*](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gnat-math-extn/index.php?title=Main_Page) and [*An Ada binding to the GNU GMP and MPFR Multiple Precision libraries*](http://code.google.com/p/adabindinggmpmpfr/) are exemplary as well as accessible.

Comment: See also [Interfacing Ada to C](http://www.ida.liu.se/edu/ugrad/progkon/Ada/ada-sw/X11Ada/doc/interf4.ps), mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8779695/230513).

Comment: See also [*Gem #59: Generating Ada bindings for C headers*](http://www.adacore.com/2009/02/23/gem-59/).

Answer (score 3):

If you have Gnat Pro (and presumably a support contract from ACT), I think you can get a [binding generator](http://www.adacore.com/wp-content/files/auto_update/gnat-unw-docs/html/gnat_ugn_29.html#SEC276) from them.

In the comments, Simon Wright pointed out that you can get this binding generator from [GCC 4.6.0.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gnat_ugn_unw/Generating-Ada-Bindings-for-C-and-C_002b_002b-headers.html#Generating-Ada-Bindings-for-C-and-C_002b_002b-headers), which is the official (although sometimes a bit behind) GCC distribution. I generally suggest folks who aren't paying ACT customers get their compiler from GCC, rather than the GNAT GPL version from ACT.

Comment: Actually available with GCC 4.6.0 (http://goo.gl/IXRjL) also, and I'd expect GNAT GPL too.

Comment: The “binding generator” link should (today) be to http://www.adacore.com/wp-content/files/auto_update/gnat-unw-docs/html/gnat_ugn_28.html#SEC275 - the `auto_update` in the link seems to mean what it says, so any deep link is subject to change without notice.

Comment: @SimonWright - Quite right, as it has changed yet again since your comment. Modified to show *today's* link. :-(