# Ada IO Multiplexing on Linux

Tags: ada

I'm trying to learn Ada on Linux by porting simple C++ tools to Ada.

Right now I' trying to write a simple serial communicaton program that sends modem commands and waits for a signalled filedescriptor using select call.

I can't seem to find the package containing the select call - do I have to look for some platform specific package here? Where would I find this? Am I even looking for the right thing here?

Comment: I think the answer depends on the nature of the serial communication interface you're trying to talk with. For TCP/IP sockets GNAT.Sockets would give you what you need (though it would be compiler-specific).  Until we know the nature of the serial port, it's hard to say what's needed for a signalled filedescriptor.

Comment: I'm just sending modem commands and wait for reply on that filedescriptor. But as T.E.D. mentionend below, maybe it's better to forego this and look into tasking. I would like to do it "the Ada" way, but had no idea where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select()` is an OS call specific to Unix, and thus isn't part of Ada's standard library.

You will either need to find a (non-standard) package that provides a Unix system call interface, wrap it yourself using interfacing pragmas, or take a different approach.

For the first option, I can only help a little, since I don't have a Unix system handy. A Posix package **should** have it, and I believe you can find one such [package (Florist) for Gnat here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnat-florist/). I can't speak to its quality.

To make your own bindings, you'd want to check out the facilities provided for this in [Appendix B of the LRM](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95lrm/ARM_HTML/RM-TOC.html). This is kind of an advanced topic though, and should not be attempted unless you either know a lot about how your OS does its subroutine linkages, or are ready to learn.

For "a different approach", look into whatever reference guide you are using has to say about Ada's tasking and/or protected objects (not to be confused with the `protected` keyword in C++). For example, you might prefer to have one task whose sole job is to read incoming data from the serial port. You can synchronize with it between reads via a rendezvous, or to get really sexy, with a queue implemented via protected object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that second approach, seems more Ada'ish.

Comment: Well, its true that if you use low-level OS interfaces to perform a task, you will end up with a lot of ugly un-Ada-like code. I'm not sure how low level Florist is. OTOH, Ada can be used as a lowish level system programming language, if that is your desire.

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928285/how-to-bind-to-opencv-for-gnat).

Comment: I think zeroc8 meant he will look into the third approach (considering the comments on his question)...

Comment: One nice thing about Ada is that you can start your counting pretty much anywhere; that's what subtypes (ranges anyway) are all about.

Comment: Well, given his user name, we should have expected he'd start at 0. :-)