# What's the meaning behind function operators in Ada?

Tags: ada

What does an operation function or whatever it's called really do? I can't really see a difference between a normal function and an operation. I could of done the following function without having the need to put an operation:

```
function "-" (Left  : in Integer;
              Right : in Float) return Float is
     
     Res : Float;
   
   begin 
      
      Res := Float(Left) - Right;
      
   return Res;
      
  end "-";
```

This operation will take two values that the user has typed in (one integer and one float) and calculate the difference between them. But what does "-" do? In my eyes it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Crucially, the `-` in the function body is a *different* `-`, namely one that takes two floats in this case. It's a fairly trivial example, but a more realistic use case might be to add arithmetic operators for arrays, for example. Then array arithmetic can be as simple as `A - B;`.

Answer (score 3):

The function provides a means to subtract floating point value from an integer value returning a floating point value. The language is strongly typed and does not provide an implicit conversion between integer and float. A function such as this explicitly performs the desired conversion.

Comment: But what’s the point of having a “-“ when I can just type A - B in my function?

Comment: For instance I can Res := Float(Left) + Right; Now if I type in 23 and 45.6 I will just get the sum of these two. So technically “-“ hasn’t done anything

Comment: @leun With the "-" operator defined, you don't have to explicitly cast the Left operand.  You can just say Res := Left + Right; and it will work assuming the type's operations are visible within the scope you are doing the subtraction in.

Comment: @leun Also consider you can make a function operator for more abstract types, like records and tagged records, which don't normally have that operation defined.  So say you create some abstract number type that is really a record with some fields to help with faster calculations.  You can define the + and - operators to make using them like numbers more seamless.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between a binary operator function (where the function name is an operator symbol such as `"-"`) and a non-operator function with two parameters is that the operator function may be called using infix notation

`A - B`

All functions, including operator functions, may be called using prefix notation

`"-" (A, B)`

Similarly for unary operators:

```
function "abs" (Right : in String) return ...

abs "Hello, World"
"abs" ("Hello, World")
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to type safety, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485385/230513), your `function` declaration is an example of [*Overloading of Operators*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-6.html). You can provide such a function as an actual parameter when [instantiating](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-3.html) a generic unit that requires a generic [formal subprogram](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-6.html#S0295); examples found among the standard library containers are summarized in this [table](https://www.adaic.com/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-8-7.html). In addition, because "Each use of a unary or binary operator is equivalent to a function_call," you can invoke such a `function` to construct an actual parameter, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33093352/230513). More generally, as outlined [here](https://www.adahome.com/9X/OOP-Ada9X.html#HDR5.2.%20%20Polymorphism26) and [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.135.7250&rep=rep1&type=pdf), overloading provides a form of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out the usage for built in types, but defining operators can also be useful for abstract data types that act like numbers.  Consider if you make your own Complex number data type.  You probably want to include all the math operations possible for it so it "acts" like a normal number:

```ada
package Complex is

    type Number is private;

    function "+"(L,R : Number) return Number;
    function "+"(L,R : Float) return Number;
    function "+"(L   : Number;
                 R   : Float) return Number;
    function "+"(L   : Float;
                 R   : Number) return Number;
                 
    -- Oher mathematical operations
                 
    function Make(Real_Part, Imaginary : Float) return Number;
    
    function Image(Self : Number) return String;

private

    type Number is record
        Real_Part : Float := 0.0;
        Imaginary : Float := 0.0;
    end record;

end Complex;
```

then you could just use it like a number in various places:

```ada
with Complex;

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Hello is

    v : Complex.Number;

    use all type Complex.Number;
begin
    Put_Line("Hello, world!");
    v := 2.0 + 3.0;
    Put_Line(Complex.Image(V));
end;
```

Another common pattern I see is converting types to and from Strings using the unary minus and plus operations.