# Variable arglists in Ada

Tags: variadic-functions, ada

Why does not Ada support variable function/procedure argument lists?
Is it hard to implement or does it somehow go against "we should keep things secure" philosophy of the language?

Varargs were over there at least as early as C and allow very handy things like printf, the likes of which can also be found in other languages like Java or C#.
Another neat example is logging functions where it is usual to pass information from all kinds of data types, not only strings, in separate arguments.

And even if this is considered non-secure technique, Ada could still make it better than at least in C by e.g. throwing an exception if there is some mismatch between format string and the actually passed arguments.

Comment: One such approach is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33093352/230513).

Comment: In Ada 83, everything has a type known by the compiler. That would not be true for such a parameter list, so such parameter lists were not allowed. Ada 83 has other features that allow implementing the same functionality, so this is no loss. In Ada 95, with the addition of programming by type extension (tagged types) this may have been less true, but since the language retained the other features that allow implementing the same functionality, there was no justification for complicating the language to add it. This remains true today.

Comment: Honestly, I'm of the opinion that such functions are fundamentally unsound and have no place in a language meant for engineering-style solutions. That said, the method used in Ada83 was to use arrays since you can have an array of any particular length.

Answer (score 3):

Ada 2022 supports interfacing to C variadic subprograms, see e.g. [ARM2022 B.3(79)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-B-3.html#p79) - also (60.16). I’ve used this with GCC 12 (the ABI for aarch64-apple-darwin differs between variadic and normal functions; this sort of issue was what prompted the change in [AI12-0028](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ai12s/ai12-0028-1.txt?rev=1.9&raw=N)).

Note, it’s still just the thinnest of skins over the C code!

Answer (score 2):

Variable argument lists made some sense in C because C does not allow overriding functions with different set argument lists, nor does C allow any useful forms of inheritance.

C and C# do not use nominative typing for scalar data types, nor do they allow the programmer to define data types and subtypes of scalar types with customized value ranges. C and C# use structural typing for scalar data types, focusing entirely on the memory layout of the data rather than the range of data for a data type.

If you want to express and integer value in the range of -10 through 10 in C you could choose to use a signed char type. The signed char type occupies 8 bits and can represent values in the range of -128 through 127. Clearly the range -10 through 10 easily fits into this type or into any other C signed integer type, but the use of whatever type you use does not limit the values of a variable you use to your selected range of -10 through 10.

If you want to express and integer value restricted to the range of -10 through 10 in Ada you can define your own type for this purpose

```ada
type my_type is range -10 .. 10;
```

Instances of my_type defined above can only contain values in the range of -10 through 10. Any attempt at runtime to assign a value out of the specified range for the type will result in the exception Constraint_Error being raised.

In C the %d format is used to print an int value while the %ld format is used to print a long value. How would you propose to provide an output format specifier for an Ada modular type or for a custom type such as

```ada
type deflection_type is range -90 .. 90;
```

The format specifier must provide a format used only for that type and not simply a type structurally similar to deflection_type. C is structurally typed and therefore only cares about the memory layout of a type. Ada is nominatively typed and does not compare types by their layout in memory.

The structural typing of C and C# scalar types opens the door for extensive cyber security vulnerabilities while the nominative typing of Ada closes the doors on those same vulnerabilities.