# Use package from a static library in ada

Tags: compiler-errors, ada

I would like to use types and services from a package which is located in a static library.

So, in my body main.adb, I put a

```
with Services.A;
```

Service.A is located in an external lib (services.a), so I need to link the lib after the compilation process.

I added the flags `-L/path/of/dir/containing/my/lib` and `-lservices`

But because of the declaration of types is inside of lib and the compilator needs the symbols, I have to include the specs (.ads) from services.ads.

I saw multiple ways to do this, but nothings works on my project.

I tried to add the flags `-I/path/to/ads` but without success.

If I add in my gpr file the specs to the Sources_Dirs, it tells me that the unit "Services.A" cannot belongs to several projects.

Is there any official ways to include the specs like a header in C from an external static library in ada ?

Comment: You say "If I add in my gpr file the specs to the Sources_Dirs, it tells me that the unit "Services.A" cannot belongs to several projects." which must mean that your GPR says `with "services.gpr";` or equivalent. Please show us both GPRs.

Comment: Yes I have a `with "services.gpr"` in order to include the specifications files needed to get the interface of my library. May I delete this inclusion and select only *.ads of the lib on my main.gpr ?

Comment: Probably. However, even the simplest version of a `services.gpr` will both build the library and enable it to be linked into a `with`-ing project. See [the documentation](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gprbuild/html/gprbuild_ug/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#library-projects). We can’t address any specific problem you may have until we see your project file! (or a cut-down equivalent that shows the same issue)

Comment: Are you trying to develop an Ada binding to `services.a`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6928285/230513)?

Comment: You mention that it’s a static library several times. What’s so important about that? what would be different if it was a dynamic library?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some stuff for you to start. I hope it can put you in a good direction.

When you use a library into a GPR, I know of 3 cases.
Keep in mind that this is not a complete answer, more cases surely exist and I may forget some things. The topic is subject to pitfalls, so you should dig more into the interwebs, AdaCore/GNAT documentation and stackoverflow, since the topic is often raised. Some of the said pitfalls might not be covered here depending on the type of libs you have/produce, and some specific compile/build/link options.

Foreword: when you include a static library, its sole file name does not tell you anything useful to invoke the code it contains. So the if the static lib is 'serivices.a', it is just a file name and extension. `with Services.A` won't be sufficient to invoke the code.

**Case 1**

You have access to the GPR `my_lib.gpr` that produces the library and it is written in Ada.
Simply include the GPR, and in your code you'll only be allowed to `with` the exposed interfaces. (it corresponds to Simon Wright comment about the `with "services.gpr";` in your GPR)

- if the `my_lib.gpr` produces a static lib, nothing to do more ! GPR does what is necessary for you (build/link).
- if the lib is dynamic (dll), then the dll need to be found at execution time in the OS search path (next to executable, or in path environment variable)

**Case 2**

You have access to the GPR `my_lib.gpr` that produces the library and it is written in another language.

- build the library
- define another GPR `my_lib_install.gpr` that contains the library interface declarations (`.ads` files). If the files do not existe, see **Case 3**.
- reference that GPR into your own GPR project
- you can now use the methods/types defined in the `.ads` files in your code. The `.ads` usually contains `pragma Import(...)` convention declaration. They are defined once, so no `unit "Services.A" cannot belongs to several projects` error message.

Or you could directly include the library interface declarations (`.ads` files) into your project.

- if the `my_lib.gpr` produces a static lib, you should include the appropriate link directives to use the .a file.
- if the lib is dynamic (dll), then the dll need to be found at execution time in the OS search path (next to executable, or in path environment variable)

**Case 3**

The library `my_lib` is a COTS and it is written in another language.
It should be delivered with interface definition.

The usual method is to write a `.ads` file(s) corresponding to the provided contract definition. The types and methods should be flagged with some `pragma Import(...)` convention corresponding to the way the library was built (Ada convention, C convention, see [ARM](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gnat_rm/Implementation-Defined-Pragmas.html) or [this wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Pragmas/Import))

Usually a the interface contract is a `.h` file (most libraries are produced with C convention). So you can use Ada's `Interfaces.c` packages which are designed for that. An example of interfacing with C is given in [this example of interfacing Ada with Java via C convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938883/interface-ada-dynamic-library-with-java-using-jna-and-adas-interface-c-packages/42938971#42938971)). The main difference is you will ahve to `pragma Import` instead of `pragma Export`
This should anwser to:

> Is there any official ways to include the specs like a header in C
>   from an external static library in ada ?

You can either directly include this `.ads` file(s) into your sources, or write your own GPR to do that hosting as indicated in the beginning. It is up to you.

Final word, if your library is coded in the Ada language, you might have a look at the documentation concerning *elaboration*, 'initialize' and 'finalize' symbols.